# Invalid number of parameters exception

Tags: python, xcopy

```
import os

surucu_adi = "G"
kaynak = surucu_adi + ":\\"
hedef = "%userprofile%\\Desktop\\pdfler\\"

for i in os.listdir(kaynak):
    dosya_konumu = kaynak + i
    if os.path.isfile(dosya_konumu):
        os.system("""xcopy /f /r /i /d /y {} {}""".format(dosya_konumu, hedef))
```

It gives error, "Invalid number of parameters"
the results of this:

```
G:\7ECxgvX2Ns_ItY3WQ4uo8zUOV95rTkGSinRjlewqHf6LmyZD-J.pdf -> C:\Users\Kadir\Desktop\pdfler\7ECxgvX2Ns_ItY3WQ4uo8zUOV95rTkGSinRjlewqHf6LmyZD-J.pdf
1 File(s) copied
G:\12114841_kamustandartlari.docx -> C:\Users\Kadir\Desktop\pdfler\12114841_kamustandartlari.docx
1 File(s) copied
Invalid number of parameters
G:\26112207_2014lys2.xlsx -> C:\Users\Kadir\Desktop\pdfler\26112207_2014lys2.xlsx
1 File(s) copied
```

Why has error?

Comment: if you run the command using the parameters posted does it work outside of python?

Comment: It would help to include the entire traceback you receive.

Comment: Try to enclose your filenames in quotes. http://superuser.com/questions/114178/why-is-xcopy-returning-invalid-number-of-parameters In Python, you need to use `"\"<filename>\""` for this.

Comment: @ScottLawson,`Invalid number of parameters`

Comment: @ScottLawson, the problem is with the xcopy command, that is the traceback.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Ah... I see now. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks you to everyone. I solved the problem.

```
os.system("""xcopy /f /r /i /d /y {} {}""".format(dosya_konumu, hedef))
```

-->

```
os.system("""xcopy {} {}""".format('"'+dosya_konumu+'"', '"'+hedef+'"'))
```

Comment: You can also just supply the double quote marks inside the formatted string: `os.system('xcopy "{}" "{}"'.format(dosya_konumu, hedef))`